# What does "a drifty car" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What does "a drifty car" mean? Does it refer to capability of instant change in the speed of car?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It refers to a car that is good for [drifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drifting_%28motorsport%29), which basically means letting the rear end of a car slide around a corner.  Rear-wheel drive cars, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If *The Fast and the Furious* is any authority on the matter, it would be a car that has a strong tendency to *drift*, or enter into a controlled (or semi-controlled) skid when turning.

According to a trailer (which anyone can feel free to link), the car tends to be light and the tires slick.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it refers to the ability of the car to "drift", basically to go into a controlled skid.